# Confused on a simple problem

Tags: inequality

I am having difficult time with a contradiction. Here is the simple math problem that I cannot understand why exactly the same technique gives two different (and contradictory) results:

The question is what is the smallest ***x*** value that satisfies the below inequality:

$$(\frac{2}{3})^{2x-1}< (\frac{27}{8})^{x-2}$$

if you rearrange the left item and solve the problem as:

$$(\frac{3}{2})^{-2x+1}<(\frac{3}{2})^{3x-6}$$
$$-2x+1<3x-6$$
$$7<5x$$
$$\frac{7}{5} < x$$ which yields **2** as the answer. However, if you rearrange the right item of the inequality the steps are:

$$(\frac{2}{3})^{2x-1}<(\frac{2}{3})^{6-3x}$$
$$2x-1<6-3x$$
$$5x<7$$
$$\frac{7}{5} > x$$
which yields **1** as the answer. where is the problem? What is the cause of this contradiction?
Thank you.

Comment: You have in effect found the only solution of the equality is when $x=\frac75$.  When $x$ is large and positive, the inequality is satisfied as the left hand side is less than $1$ and the right hand side greater than $1$; for similar reasons the inequality is not satisfied when $x$ is large and negative.  So you first approach gets the correct answer.  Your second has an error of ignoring that $\frac23 <1$ and $\log(2/3) <0$ so reversing the inequality. You should have $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2x-1}<\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{6-3x} \implies 2x-1>6-3x$

Comment: Aside: your jump from $\frac75$ to $2$ or $1$ is implying that $x$ must be an integer, which you've not otherwise said.  On the other hand, "the smallest $x$ such that $x>\frac75$" doesn't really make sense, because there is no such $x$ (instead of "smallest", you could ask for the "greatest lower bound" of all such $x$ values).  (Also, the smallest $x$ such that $x<\frac75$ is negative infinity, by that same interpretation.)

Answer (score 10):

Note that $x\to b^x$ is strictly increasing when $b>1$ and therefore
$$b^x<b^y\Leftrightarrow x<y.$$
You applied this property correctly for $b=3/2>1$.

On the other hand, $x\to b^x$ is strictly decreasing when $0<b<1$ and therefore we have
$$b^x<b^y\Leftrightarrow x>y.$$
Hence for $b=2/3<1$ you should find the reversed inequality
$$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2x-1}<\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{6-3x}\Leftrightarrow 2x-1>6-3x$$
which leads to the same result.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you have to invert the sign of inequality while taking logarithm depending upon whether base of log $>1$ or $<1$.
This is because $a^x$ is an increasing function if $a>1$, but it is a decreasing function if $a<1$, hence log with respect to $a$ follows a similar behavior.
If you invert the inequality sign while taking log with respect to base $\frac 23$, answer would match.